# Jinja not using variable within html tag

Tags: python, jinja2

I am trying to use a Jinja variable from a dictionary within an html tag but it is not showing up for some reason. Thanks in advance for any help

```
dictionary = ["HTML": "1", "Flask": "2", "Python": "3", "CSS": "4"]

<th style="display:inline-block;" id="{{ helloworld }}">Program number {{ dictionary[HTML] }}</th>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code snippet, you use HTML as a variable, not as a key.

Does

`{{ dictionary['HTML'] }}`

help?